# Networkdays Loop - I Want to get the Networkdays loop . but giving an error. I am using office 2016. appreciate your efforts in advance

Tags: vba, worksheet-function

> i am trying networkdays loop in office 2016 but not getting through.

```
Sub Macro8()
    
    Dim N As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    
    
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    N = Sheets("Dump").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Range("E1") = Date 'i want to use today's date as lastest date to find the networkdays
                For i = 2 To N
                
                Cells(i, 4).Formula = wf.NetworkDays(Cells(i, 3), Cells(1, 5))
    
    Next N
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is the i counter wasn't defined and when you're closing the loop should be "Next i". It's not necessary to set the worksheetfunction.

Try this:

```
Sub TEST_NetworkDays()

    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    
    N = Sheets("Dump").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    Range("E1") = Date 'i want to use today's date as lastest date to find the networkdays
    
    For i = 2 To N
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(Cells(i, 3), Cells(1, 5))
    Next i
    
    'with Holidays
    For i = 2 To N
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(Cells(i, 3), Cells(1, 5), Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(12, 9)))
    Next i
End Sub
```